# Openssl cannot decrypt message using PuttyGen private key

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

I've created public and private keys using PuttyGen then the public key was used to encrypt a message.
I am now trying to decrypt such message using the private key with the following command:

```
echo [my encrypted message] | openssl enc -d -base64 -A | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/private.ppk
```

but I get the error:

```
unable to load Private Key
6870300:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

The private key looks like this (actual key omitted):

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20170724
Public-Lines: 6
[...]
Private-Lines: 14
[...]
Private-MAC: [...]
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this guy](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs/issues/93) I sorted it out.

I've reopened the private key with PuttyGen and exported as OpenSSH, then used this new file to decrypt the message.